# Allergies in brand new apartment

Tags: carpet, chemicals

Recently I moved into a new apartment, and have had pretty bad allergies since. I wake up with  allergies that last a few hours and then go away around lunch time, but the allergies return at night.

Before moving into this apartment, I never really had allergies.

I figured it was the carpet since I read brand new carpet can leave chemicals in the air, so I bought a vacuum and have since vacuumed the entire apartment several times. I also had the apartment management hire a professional deep carpet cleaner person come out and clean the carpets. Still the allergies are pretty bad.

I bought a Winix air purifier that works really well though. The only downside is, it only purifies the room it is in and not the entire apartment. When I move it from one room to another, the air quality detector on the air purifier usually turns orange/red which means the air quality is poor. The air purifier automatically goes to the high setting in this case which moves a lot of air and cleans it fast, but again it does not clean the whole apartment air.

All the windows are sealed off using a plastic window film kit to save energy if it makes a difference.

You can literally feel the air quality not as good in a room where the air purifier has not been for a while. I am really trying to beat these allergies, but need new suggestions on what could be causing it.

Comment: Did you undergo an allergy test? Describe your symptoms, please.

Comment: There are so many things this could be. I'd start with a doctor's visit

Comment: "Alergies" can be anything from rashes to trouble breathing to giant boils.  What are you actually experiencing?  It may not be alergies - you may want to have someone come in and do air quality testing.

Comment: @Ariser Scratchy throat, watery eyes that get itchy, sneezing, running nose for hours.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about medical problems, not do-it-yourself home improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest going to an otolaryngologist to get a diagnosis. It may be allergies, or it may just be something else that coincides with your move. If it's allergies, you can get tested and get a better idea of what specific environmental factors may be causing your symptoms.

Have you tried taking over-the-counter allergy medicine to see if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

One has to think, why the symptoms come at night and aren't present at noon. If your carpet produces allergens, the symptoms usually will be present around the clock. Assuming an allergic reaction, there are unfortunately two possible cases: an immediate reaction to the allergens and a delayed one. The delayed reaction can happen up to 12 hours after contact to the allergen.

So, if there's an immediate reaction, maybe it has something to do with your sleep. If you know your bed (I want to say, you owned it before you moved) it is probably not involved. There are many possibilities, even a cockroach allergy, because those guys tend to drink saliva from dormant people's mouths.

But if you suffer from a delayed type, it may also be possible that your allergy is triggered by something you ingest during the day.

Further possibilities:

- A pseudo allergy, from contact to chemicals (perhaps from the carpet)
- Mold. To rule that out, I recommend to measure the air humidity over the day.

But all those hints cannot replace a consultation of a dermatologist including an allergy test.